# How to hide credit card details on invoice PDF?

Tags: orders, magento2.3, invoice, credit-card

I don't want to display the credit card details on invoice PDF.

How can I achieve this programmatically? In which file should I do the modification?

Please[image] check the attached image

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by pluginize or Overwrite.

> vendor/magento/module-authorizenet/Block/Adminhtml/Order/View/Info/PaymentDetails.php

Change the template and modify there which field you want to hide.

```
/**
 * Render as PDF
 * @return string
 */
public function toPdf()
{
    $this->setTemplate('Magento_Payment::info/pdf/default.phtml');
    return $this->toHtml();
}
```

**This is not tested code.**

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer of above question

Need to change the $payment variable output in below file:

app/code/core/mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Abstract.php

> 1) just debug the $payment variable and check the output... line # 434
>
> 2) then when you draw the output then check for the foreach output.
>   line #530

you can exclude the details of credit card by modifying the code from above two sections mentioned lines

Comment: but modify the code in core file is not a good idea.